# create a "go to a random page of the website function"

Tags: javascript, html, random

For  a project i am trying to create a special way to browse through a website by having a "go to random page" button, similar to the way wikipedia does it here [wikipage random button on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT0l6.png), see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page.

for this purpose I have to question.
A - Is it possible to create a function that search all the existing index[].html on my website and puts them into an array ?
B - Is it possible to dynamically update this array as I am adding new pages to my website (like wikipedia adds new articles) ?

basically something like this ! thank you !

find a way to go through the website and add all html to an array

```
var diary = ["index1.html", "index2.html", '...'];
```

access random page

```
function accessrandompage() {
var randompage = Math.floor(Math.random() * diary.length);
window.location.replace("index" + randompage + ".html");
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a CMS?

Comment: mmh I am no sure what you mean, sorry... (I am new to making websites, usually just for fun so not aware of the right vocabulary)

Comment: You're asking if it's possible... yes. How? In many ways. --- How do you expect to update the diary array?

Comment: The best would that when the button is triggered, it looks through all pages with "number.index.html" to count them and push them in the array. As for how this could be done, I don't know what i would need...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a variable `pagesCount` that stands for the number of pages that your website currently has.

Then, create a function called addwebsite(). Inside this function, you add the code to create a new page, while also incrementing `pagesCount` by 1.